# Run-time error '91' trying to create a dynamic embedded chart with a scrollbar

Tags: excel, vba, scrollbar, excel-charts

I'm trying to write a VBA subroutine that adds an embedded line chart to a sheet, and because there's a great deal of data, I'd like to show 200 datapoints and scroll through the entire series using a scrollbar. Rather than having to edit the data series by clicking on the Formulas ribbon tab and then Use in Formula and changing the series values by pasting named ranges, I recorded the macro so that I could cut and paste the generated code to automate the process. Unfortunately, it is these last 2 lines of VBA generated code that are the problem.

Here is my code-

```
Sub dynamic_chart()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim embedCht As Chart

    Set embedCht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlLine).Chart
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Dates", RefersToR1C1:="=OFFSET(Sheet1!R1C1,Sheet1!R1C3+1,0,200,1)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Close", RefersToR1C1:="=OFFSET(Sheet1!R1C2,Sheet1!R1C3+1,0,200,1)"
    embedCht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = 45
    
    ActiveSheet.ScrollBars.Add(5, 374, 1110, 20).Select
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Scroll Bar 1")).Select
    With Selection
        .Value = 0
        .Min = 0
        .Max = lastRow - 200
        .SmallChange = 50
        .LargeChange = 200
        .LinkedCell = "$C$1"
        .Display3DShading = True
    End With

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "==scrolling.xlsm!Close"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "==scrolling.xlsm!Dates"

End Sub
```

It's the last 2 lines of code that prompt the Run-time error '91'
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe change ActiveChart to embedCht. And check out those ”==“: should they be “=“?

Comment: Thanks Clifford. I did try both suggestions previously, but to no avail.